# Codeigniter FTP Class

Tags: codeigniter, ftp

i need to upload a zip from my localhost to my webserver with my codeigniter application.
I have followed the docs but i can't upload file, the error is:

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to locate the source file. Please check your path.
```

i can't figured out why it can't find the source path, if i try to test the path with `file_exists` it work, but with the `upload` method fails...

This is my code:

```
$this->load->library('ftp');

$config_ftp['hostname'] = 'xxxxx';
$config_ftp['username'] = 'xxxxx';
$config_ftp['password'] = 'xxxxx';
$config_ftp['debug']    = TRUE;

$this->ftp->connect($config_ftp);

if(file_exists($my_file))
    echo "ok";
else
    echo "no";

$this->ftp->upload($my_file , '/web/'.$my_file, 'binary');
```

Comment: If you use the `FCPATH` constant, this will provide you the Path that contains the bootstrap `index.php`. From there, you can build the path to the file you want to upload.

Comment: Can you show the contents of `$my_file`? Also try using absolute path if you're not doing that already.

Comment: With `FCPATH` i get the path from the localhost: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AllWorks/Giovanetti2012/gestionale/` at this i have append the `$my_file` that contains the path from the `gestionale` folder to the zip file and the new path is: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AllWork/Giovanetti2012/gestionale/files/xml/auto/archive.zip` but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you check the file permissions on the folder / file?

Comment: Yes, i have all the permission...by now i use the ftp function here: `http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php`and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the standard php function for the ftp and now it works